# Philips TAPH805-BK wireless headphones mic not working on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: bluetooth, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone, headphones

My microphone is notworking, although the my headphones' speakers are working just fine. The headphones work correctly when used on my mobile phone, so I am certain that the issue is with some connection with Ubuntu.

I have tried a bunch of other solutions available on the web, tried using `blueman`, `alsamixer`, even `pulseaudio`, but nothing seems to work.

Any insights or ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking if Bluetooth is connected to the right device?

Also make sure to go to Settings → *Sound* and check if the microphone's volume is high enough.

[image: Input Device sound settings]

Hope that solves your issue :)

Comment: i have tried that, it displays only one mic, systems mic not headphones mic